# Android DataStore read triggered by different key write

Tags: android, coroutine, datastore

By looking the document, [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore), I have the setup

build.gradle.kts

```
implementation ("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
```

MainActivity.kt

```
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val MY_COUNTER_1 = intPreferencesKey("my_counter_1")
    val MY_COUNTER_2 = intPreferencesKey("my_counter_2")

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        dataStore.data
            .map { currentPreferences ->
                // Unlike Proto DataStore, there's no type safety here.
                currentPreferences[MY_COUNTER_1] ?: 0
            }.collect {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Counter 1: $it")
            }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        dataStore.data
            .map { currentPreferences ->
                // Unlike Proto DataStore, there's no type safety here.
                currentPreferences[MY_COUNTER_2] ?: 0
            }.collect {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Counter 2: $it")
            }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        while (true) {
            dataStore.edit { currentPreferences ->
                val currentCounterValue = currentPreferences[MY_COUNTER_2] ?: 0
                currentPreferences[MY_COUNTER_2] = currentCounterValue + 1
            }
            delay(3000)
        }
    }
```

I found that when `MY_COUNTER_2` is written with new values, `MY_COUNTER_1` read is also triggered. I expected to see `MY_COUNTER_2` read only, do I mis-config my DataStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/datastore/core/DataStore#data()) says about the `data` function:

> val data: Flow 
> Provides [...] access to the latest durably persisted state. 
> Returns a flow representing the current state of the data

This sounds like the `Flow` will emit a new value whenever **any** value in the `DataStore` changes. The newly emitted value will be an object that holds all current preferences that are stored in the `DataStore`. You then filter the desired preference by its key, and `collect` will always process the value, even if the value actually has not changed.

If you want to `collect` the value of a specific preference only if it actually changes, try out the [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/distinct-until-changed.html) function:

```
 dataStore.data
    .map { currentPreferences ->
        currentPreferences[MY_COUNTER_1] ?: 0
    }.distinctUntilChanged().collect {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Counter 1: $it")
    }
```

Comment: I did not look the document of the `data` function, it makes sense after reading. The additional info about `distinctUntilChanged` is also very helpful, thx a lot for sharing those info.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that `distinctUntilChanged()` does the job for you!